# Cannot provide a value for property 'JSModalModule' on type 'Blazorise.Modal'

Tags: c#, telerik, abp, blazorise

I'm trying to replace Blazorise with Telerik Ui .
im using Abp FrameWork , Blazor Server-Side.

the challenge was to convert all my Blazorise components to telerik , which was not fun :|
they have similarities with Components name , like `<Card>` component.

i managed to run my app , and there is no compile time error . but now , after starting my blazor app , i get this message. i followed the Telerik Blazor Server Installation steps as it was.

but now i'm lost.

The Error :

```
 Cannot provide a value for property 'JSModalModule' on type 'Blazorise.Modal'
 There is no registered service of type 'Blazorise.Modules.IJSModalModule'.   
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

my DevelopBlazorModule :

```
 private void ConfigureLayout()
 {
     Configure<AbpLayoutHookOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.Add(
             LayoutHooks.Head.Last,
             typeof(MainLayoutComponent),
             StandardLayouts.Application
         );
     });
 }

 private void ConfigureTelerik(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
 {
     context.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();
 }
```